# Using Codeception with Laravel and subdomains

Tags: subdomain, codeception, laravel-5

I was hoping to use Codeception to handle a subdomain declared in Laravel 5

```
$router->group(array('domain' => 'admin.' . Config::get('app.host')), function()
{
```

Codeception appears to have an amOnSubdomain method for webdriver, but not for the Laravel 4 module.

http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#amOnSubdomain

Is there a way to integrate this functionality with Codeception on Laravel?

I tried calling the action directly

```
$I->amOnAction('Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
```

But this throws an error

```
Can't be on action "Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm":
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException:
```

A bit confused on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I set an alias with the `as` index and it worked for me:

```
Route::post('/login', ['as' => 'admin.login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@postLogin']);

$I->amOnRoute('admin.login');
```

I also submitted an issue to the codeception repo for this method to be added. I looked into moving the method over from another module that has it already but the laravel module does some different things with it's url and history, and don't have the time at the moment to look into it more. Hopefully that method will work for you.

https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/1505

Comment: I didn't think to try amOnRoute instead of amOnAction, actually there may have been some issues with action as things were being moved around. In the end we just decided to drop the admin.domain.com and go with domain.com/admin :D